# Qt: How to print QFile?

Tags: qt, qfile, qprinter

Actually, I have a CSV file generated via Qt. I need to add a print option for the user to print the CSV file as it is without opening the file, if possible.

I tried to search the for the solution. But couldn't find a way to resolve the issue.

Can any one suggest me the way to Print QFile ?? Is there any function that prints QFile ??

Comment: I think you'll have to program that yourself.

Comment: To get any data from the file you have to open it. It is thus impossible to print a file before opening it. The opening is an operation done at the OS API level, it doesn't mean displaying anything to the user. Of course, to print a text file you still need to format it in some way!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by print. Printing the raw content (i.e. with the comma delimiter) to stdout, or you want a fancy printout of the CSV table, and so on?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just want to Print CSV with comman delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `QTextDocument` set up with the contents of the CSV and call the `print()` method.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you already have the contents generated and eventually want to print a preview before saving to CSV file?

Comment: Sebastian Lange, Thanks for your reply. I guess QTextDocument has an option only for html ie "setHtml()". And I have QString. Actually, I have a QSqlTabelModel which is shown via QTableView then as per user choice it can be saved as an CSV file.I also want to add an option for the user to print it directly. So what I have is the data as an QString.

Comment: It does support ```setPlainText(const QString &text)```, which will result in a default formating by the document. Which after calling setPlainText can be printed by print-method.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I tried your suggestion. Its wrapping extra columns on next line. In My case, I have 24 columns with Headers. This process is able to print 12-15 columns on first line and rest are wrapped up to second line. (Something like c1-c12,\n c13-c24) Can you help me aur suggest me to remove this bug ??

Comment: Try updating the page using ```QTextDocument::setPageSize(QSizeF &fsize)```.

Answer (score 0):

are you using linux? run this terminal command using QProcess

```
lpr -P "printername" "path+filename"
```

EDIT:
Try this since you are using windows

```
c:> lpr -Sprinter's IP address [-Poption] [-ol] \path\file name
```

from http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001042/0001042969/view/netsys/int/0207.htm but Im not able to test it because I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks reggie. Your idea is good. I am using Windows xp. Is there similar Dos command for default printer? Its a good hint that i can try with.